# what does <C-\>^] mean in vim mapping?

Tags: vim, mapping, key

Says in the gtags tutorials:
    Suggested map:

```
    map <C-\>^] :GtagsCursor<CR>

Though the mapping of :GtagsCursor to ^] seems suitable, it will bring an
inconvenience in the help screen.
```

I guess ^] should mean CTRL-], but cannot find explicit descriptions about it in the chapter "key-mapping".
Another question is if ^] is CTRL-], why use ^] here?

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed inconsistent, and would be more understandable as `:map <C-\><C-]>`. In Vim (as well as in terminals), the combination of `[` + `Key` stands for the single `<C-Key>`. You'd enter this via `<C-V><C-]>`, **not** as the two characters `^` and `]`.

The mapping suggests the combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with two keys because `<C-]>` by itself is already taken for keyword jumps.

Comment: What does `[` + `Key` have to do with it?